# How can i get output array having only different key?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have following two array

```html
$array1 = array("product_a" => "Nokia1", "product_b" => "Nokia11", "product_c" => "Nokia111", "Nokia1111");
$array2 = array("product_a" => "Nokia1", "Samsung", "Nokia1111");
```

I want to compare these both array and want output as having different keys

Like my output as below

```html
Array
(
    [product_b] => Nokia11
    [product_c] => Nokia111
    [0] => Nokia1111
)
```

is there any default php method available to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can try

```html
function key_compare_func($a, $b)
{
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;
}
```

You can get some reference with following link too,

http://questionnanswer.com/questions/view_question/80/category_list:2/how-can-get-different-key-array?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ok. got it. Yes you are right. may be this link expired in future.